# Java print out words from a string into an array

Tags: java

I want to take user input for whatever words they may enter through a buffered reader and put them into an array. Then I want to print out each word on a separate line. So I know I need some sort of a word counter to count the number of words the user inputs. This is what I have thus far.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inputValue;

        inputValue = input.readLine();
        String[] words = inputValue.split("\\s+");
```

Lets say the users enter the words `here is a test run`. The program should count 5 values and print out the words as such

```
here
is
a
test
run
```

Any help or suggestions on which way to approach this?

Comment: You're very close. Hint: What you're looking for is a loop, probably a `for`: [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no need to count the words (unless you really want to). You could instead use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
String[] words = inputValue.split("\\s+");
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

As I said, if you *really* want to, then you could get the [`length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) of an array (your "count") and then use a regular `for` loop like

```
String[] words = inputValue.split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

If you don't need each word on a separate line, then you could also use [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) and something like

```
String[] words = inputValue.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not answering homework.  If so you should tag it as such.  Here are two approaches you might try.

```
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String inputValue = input.readLine();
    String[] words = inputValue.split("\\s+");

    // solution 2
    for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
        System.out.println(words[i]);
    }

    // solution 1
    System.out.println(inputValue.replaceAll("\\s+", "\n"));
```

Live Demo: http://ideone.com/bCucIh